# Deleting documents in a batch by expiration date in ravenDB

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am trying to delete documents older than a certain point in ravenDB.  I am still unfamiliar with Lucene and am having a hard time constructing this query.

```
        _Session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(
            typeof(AssetsByExpirationDate).Name,
            new IndexQuery()
            {
                Query = string.Format("ExpirationDate:[\"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}\" TO \"{1:MM/dd/yyyy}\"]", DateTime.MinValue, new DateTime(2012,6,1))
            });
```

What is the correct syntax for the Query to delete items before a certain date?

Comment: Why not use the expiry bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build your query outside the DatabaseCommands IndexQuery and use Query.ToString() to populate the IndexQuery Query string as below :

```
        var query = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset, AssetsByExpirationDate>()
            .WhereBetween("ExpirationDate",DateTime.MinValue,new DateTime(2012, 6, 1));

        var queryString = query.ToString();

        session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(typeof(AssetsByExpirationDate).Name, new IndexQuery
        {
            Query = queryString
        });
```

Using this way and if you are not very familiar with lucene query syntax, RavenDb Query API build it for you as shown before by calling .ToString() and got the following Lucene formatted query string.

```
ExpirationDate:{00010101000000000 TO 20120601000000000}
```

Note that deleting using DatabaseCommands does't work with stale indexes. So be careful or use a standard lucene query to retrieve documents to delete and then perform a simple **Session.Delete(asset)** foreach documents to delete.

```
        var query = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Asset, AssetsByExpirationDate>()
            .WhereBetween("ExpirationDate",DateTime.MinValue,new DateTime(2012, 6, 1));
        var assets = query.ToList();

        foreach(var asset in assets)
        {
            session.Delete<Asset>(asset);
        }

        session.SaveChanges();
```

Pay **attention** to pagination, since **Ravendb returns only 128 results by default**.

Comment: I'm deleting 30 to 40 thousand items at a time.  Delete by index is the most efficient way of doing this for my scenario.  I'm not too concerned about the index being stale, I am running this every couple of minutes so it'll hit the index again later when it's not stale.

Thanks!  I hadn't known abut the LuceneQuery feature.

Comment: A slightly nicer way of doing this is by using the built-in RavenDB functions, see https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Abstractions/Linq/DateTools.cs